# is there any way to notify the doctor/physician to meet the patient in emergency using hl7 message

Tags: hl7, medical

Situation: Patient monitor system has alarmed to the nursing station that the patient is undergone to serious, then we need to notify the doctor/physician to check this situation. I know that using alarm messages we can notify the nursing station. But is there any hl7 messages/format to notify/order the doctor to look after the patient/situation?

It will be great if you looking into the solution for this.

Comment: shall we use OCR/OBR messages as ORDER to check patient to physician??

Comment: Maybe the tutorial mentioned here helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544278/android-java-parsing-hl7-message-with-hapi-v-2-2-with-defaulthapicontext

Comment: @Josh - it couldn't help.. anyway thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Look at  R40, R41, R42 message triggers.

Answer (score 0):

The R42 trigger event is used for observation reports that identify a device-sourced event (e.g., transition on an infusion pump between primary and secondary modes of operation) that is relevant to clinical workflow but that does not require a response from a clinician or clinical management system (in which case, an R40 alert message should be used).

R42 messages do not need to provide for an application level response, as does the ORU^R40 message (via the ORA^R41 message).